# Why is sampling 50% of observations in stochastic gradient boosting equivalent to bootstrap sampling?

Tags: bootstrap, stochastic-processes, boosting

In the stochastic gradient boosting paper, Friedman (2002) writes that sampling half of the observations before each iteration is "roughly equivalent to drawing bootstrap samples at each iteration". What is the rationale for this? He doesn't explain it, and I'm having a hard time understanding why that would be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Because a bootstrap by definition involves drawing a random sample (with replacement) which has the same sample size as the original dataset, i.e., $n$ objects.  On average, when randomly drawing $n$ objects **with replacement** from a sample of $n$ objects, the probability that an object will not be selected is $(1-1/n)^n=\exp(-1)=0.368$. Thus, the probability that an object will be drawn into the bootstrap sample is $1-0.368 = 0.632$.  So Friedman is most likely saying that the 0.5 is close to the 0.6.